# BEP-20 Token Transfer Error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, bsc, transfer

I am unable to transfer test tokens from my address (say address A) to another address B. The steps I did were

1. deploy and verify a rebase contract, all tokens were automatically sent to my address.
2. Then I made address B the owner.
3. Afterwards, I am trying to transfer my tokens from A to B using metamask but im unable to do so. Here is the [link](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xe20bc7d818e53674960799d253aebb84926c281cdf8756f4ceddf38cd85805f9) of the failed transaction. And this is the [smart contrac](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xe97175962a2deaf92d10aaf23f5998a27d683b4b)t.

BSC blockexplorer says

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution
> reverted]    BEP-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate
> corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an infinite number of ways in which an ERC-20/ BEP-20 contract can be implemented.

In your case, the token contract has two modifiers set on the `transfer` function:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 value)
    external
    override
    validRecipient(to)
    initialDistributionLock
    returns (bool)
{
    _transferFrom(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
}
```

Your contract call passes the first modifier `validRecipient` because that checks only whether the recipient is not the zero address. But the second modifier `initialDistributionLock` ...

```
modifier initialDistributionLock() {
    require(
        initialDistributionFinished ||
        isOwner() ||
        allowTransfer[msg.sender]
    );
    _;
}
```

`initialDistributionFinished` is a storage boolean that is currently set to `false`. And since `0x82a55de9d15b13eb6db1b6526d9e6e2e25397903` is neither the owner of the contract nor it has enabled transfers by being set in the `allowTransfer` mapping, the contract call is reverted.

Therefore, transfers are disabled during the "initial distribution" phase. If you have access to the owner account, you should be able to set this flag to `true` and make your transfer.